# Split a vector into an array of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I want to split one vector of bytes into an array with equal vector of bytes
for example if I have

```
std::vector<uint8_t> vec{11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88};
std::array<std::vector<uint8_t>, N> arr; // N is the number of subvectors from the vector vec
```

if N == 4 the content of arr will be 4 vectors each vector contains 2 elements
{ {11,22}, {33,44}, {55,66}, {77,88} }

Comment: What behavior do you expect if `vec.size()` is not divisible by `N`? Do remaining split pieces get empty vectors, or is it an error?

Comment: the one who provide the vector will provide also N and and if he put a wrong data I will return an exception for him

Comment: StackOverflow is a not free code-writing service. You have to try something first by yourself. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/580083)

Comment: its one loop, maybe two. You shuold really try to write something yourself, once you know how exactly you want to do it you can consider to look for an algorithm for "nicer" code, but please try to get some code first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a hard-error if `N` does not divide evenly into `vec.size()`, this is actually pretty simple to solve. The basic logic would be:

1. Check that the input can be split correctly (throw on failure)
2. Create `N` vectors in an array as a result
3. Reserve space for `vec.size() / N` for each vector in that array (optional)
4. Store `vec.size() / N` from the original `vec` in each vector (basically, loop through `vec.size() / N` elements from `vec`, and store in result vector)

Since the result is a `std::array`, the size must be statically specified -- which means that for the user to be able to specify this number, it can only be done with a `template` non-type parameter for `N`. For example:

```cpp
#include <vector>  // std::vector
#include <cstdint> // std::uint8_t
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t
#include <stdexcept> // std::runtime_error
#include <cassert>   // assert
#include <array> // std::array

template <std::size_t N>
auto split(const std::vector<std::uint8_t>& vec) -> std::array<std::vector<std::uint8_t>, N>
{
    // Handle the error case
    if (vec.size() % N != 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"vec.size() is not divisible by N"};
    }

    const auto values_per_container = vec.size() / N;
    auto result = std::array<std::vector<std::uint8_t>, N>{};
    
    auto i = 0u;

    // Iterate through the vectors in the array
    for (auto& v : result) {
        v.reserve(values_per_container);

        // Store 'vec.size() / N' objects per container
        for (auto j = 0; j < values_per_container; ++j, ++i) {
            assert(i < vec.size());

            v.push_back(vec[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Using `i` as the index here to iterate through the input `vec` is safe, and should be an invariant of this code -- since we first ensure that `vec.size() / N` is valid. Hence the use of `assert` here

Here's an example on [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3dGYEP)